# Windows Not Utilizing All Logical Processors

Tags: windows, cpu, affinity, logical-processor

(I originally posted this on Stack Overflow but was directed here. I apologize if this isn't the appropriate forum.)

We have a controller application which starts simulation applications asynchronously. (Both applications are written in C++ and run on Windows.) Our applications are single threaded (although it's possible 3rd party libraries use worker threads). The controller application relies on the OS to optimally utilize logical processors.

A user has a Dell computer with 12 cores and 24 logical processors, running Windows 10 Enterprise. The computer is dedicated to running simulations, with minimal background activity. The user configured the controller to start 24 simulation processes, expecting all logical processors would be utilized. Instead, the user observed that 12 logical processors were utilized (per Process Explorer):
[12 logical processors used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtkLz.jpg)

In the Process Explorer Set Affinity dialog, the controller process has all 24 logical processors checked. This behavior has since been observed on other computers and isn't specific to the user.

I modified the controller to call the Windows API function SetProcessAfinityMask(), assigning each simulation process to its own logical processor, and was able to utilize all 24 logical processors (per Process Explorer):
[24 logical processors used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6t6W.jpg)

In the Processor Explorer Set Affinity dialog, each simulation process has only its assigned logical processor checked.

Our applications, although currently Windows only, are largely platform neutral and I would prefer to let the OS handle the scheduling (rather than injecting low-level OS API calls).

My questions are:

- Why doesn't Windows utilize all logical processors?
- Are there settings which control this behavior? (Currently it would be for Windows 8.1, 10 and 11.)
- If it's necessary to inject the low-level OS API calls, are there things to do (or not do)? For instance, even though the computer is dedicated to running simulations, would it be best to leave 1-2 logical processors for background activity?

I'm new to this - until I started researching the user's question I wasn't aware of processor affinity - so I apologize if I missed something in searching the Web. The email exchange with the user is lengthy, with many things discussed, tried and ruled out as a solution. I tried to provide enough, but not an overwhelming amount, of detail. I'll be happy to provide additional information if it will be helpful.

Comment: The ultimate test would be if it’s actually faster now. ;-) // Hyperthreading doesn’t mean a CPU core can actually execute two threads entirely concurrently. It’s a complex topic, but if both threads use the same function units, the speedup will be minimal. // It could also be related to data leaks that can occur with thread cohabitation on the same physical core.

Comment: I'd be wondering how you are launching the processes when they end up only on half the cores. Are you using some specific call or method of launching?

Comment: Though I'm an absolute amateur at this, I've always found that launching single-threaded processes equal to the number of *actual* cores rather than HT cores actually gives the greatest work output. It requires no intervention to persuade the OS to do this, in my limited experience. [This works very well for VMs running code compiling or extensive video processes too.] HT cores each get a shared time slot, they can't both be using the core at the same time.

Comment: what kind of CPU is it? is it possible that this is a dual socket board and you actually have 2 CPUs each with 6 cores/12 logical cores?

Comment: “Why doesn't Windows utilize all logical processors?” - Windows does and is using all logical processors.  Your application wasn’t due to how it was coded. This seems more of a SO question, specifically, “how do I write multi-threaded software that’s platform independent” but that would require you providing your current core count code. Given you fixed this issue with code, I have absolutely no idea, why SO directed you to Super User since the platform independent solution also will require code. You should delete this question and edit your original SO question so it can be reopened

Comment: To be clear, you need to set each simulation process to its own thread, if only 12 cores were being used your “number of threads possible detection code”, was to blame hence the reason your code change to set the affinity solved the problem. I have been programming for more than 20 years.